# Cordova Media Plugin Record audio Error

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, audio

I built an Android application to record audio using the Cordova media plugin.

When I press the record button, it creates an audio file.

Once the recoding is complete:

- If I press back button then the audio file is empty.
- If go to the location by pressing the home key then the audio file is OK and playable.

How can I fix this behaviour when using the back button?

```js
.controller('myController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaMedia,$cordovaDevice , $timeout, $interval) {

  $scope.timerWithInterval = 0;
  //$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  try {
      
    $scope.timerWithInterval = 0;
    var mediaRec;

    $scope.startRecord = function() {

      $scope.timerWithInterval = 0;
      if($scope.myInterval){
        $interval.cancel($scope.myInterval);
      }
      $scope.onInterval = function(){
         $scope.timerWithInterval++;
      }
      $scope.circle = "outer-circle-active";
      $scope.myInterval = $interval($scope.onInterval,1000);

      var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
      var src = "myrecording_"+random+".mp3";

      $scope.mmediaRec = new Media(src,
      // success callback
      function(e) {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
      },

      // error callback
      function(err) {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
      });


      // Record audio
      $scope.mmediaRec.startRecord();
    };


    $scope.stopRecord = function() {
      $scope.timerWithInterval = 0;
      $interval.cancel($scope.myInterval);
      $scope.staus = "successfully saved";
      $scope.mmediaRec.stopRecord();
      mediaRec.release();
    };


  } catch (e) {
      console.warn("onDeviceReady error: " + e)
      alert("onDeviceReady error: " + e);
    }
  //});
})
```